# variable with memory issue?

Tags: android, corrupt-data

I have 3 variables: i j k. i = 9 and j k = 0. my code is doing the following test: if(i>j && i>k) and I don't get a match.

If I detail the test, i>j works and i>k not.

Am I missing something abvious?

[image]

here is the code:

```
   private void showReport(){
        int i,j,k,l;
        i = results[0];
        j = results[1];
        k = results[2];
        men2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        men3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String s = Integer.toString(i);
    res1.setText(s);
    s = Integer.toString(j);
    res2.setText(s);
    s = Integer.toString(k);
    res3.setText(s);

    if(lang == 0){
        if(i==MAX_LIST || j==MAX_LIST || k==MAX_LIST ){
            title34.setText("AWESOME!!! You found all the words!");
            return;
        }
        if (i<j && j<k)
            if(k>12)
                title34.setText("Excellent - you scored a very high score of " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " good responses and you demonstrated a regular progression");
            else if(k>8) // very good - linear progression
                title34.setText("Excellent - you scored " + Integer.toString(k) +
                " good responses and you demonstrated a regular progression");
            else
                title34.setText("Very good - you demonstrated a regular progression. You just need to focus on your score");
        else if (k > i && i>4)
            if(k>12)
                title34.setText("Excellent - you scored a very high score of " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " good responses and you demonstrated a regular progression");
            else if(k>8) // very good - linear progression
                title34.setText("Excellent - you scored " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " good responses and you demonstrated a regular progression");
            else
                title34.setText("Very good - you demonstrated a regular progression. You just need to focus on your score");
        else {
            if (i > j && i > k)
                l = i;
            if (j > i && j > k)
                l = j;
            else
                l = k;
            if (l > 12)
                title34.setText("Excellent - you scored a very high score of " + Integer.toString(l) + "Try to improve your progression.");
            else if (l > 8)
                title34.setText("Very good - you scored " + Integer.toString(l) +
                        " good responses. Try to improve your progression.");
            else
                title34.setText("Try another time.");
        }
    }
    else {
        if(i==MAX_LIST || j==MAX_LIST || k==MAX_LIST ){
            title34.setText("BRAVO!!! vous avez trouvé tous les mots!");
            return;
        }
        if (i<j && j<k)
            if(k>12)
                title34.setText("Excellent score! il est de " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " bonnes réponses et vous avez démontré une progression régulière.");
            else if(k>8) // very good - linear progression
                title34.setText("Excellent - votre meilleur score est de " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " bonnes réponses et vous avez démontré une progression régulière.");
            else
                title34.setText("Très bien - vous avez démontré une progression régulière. Vous devez améliorer votre score.");
        else if (k > i && i>4)
            if(k>12)
                title34.setText("Excellent score! il est de " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " bonnes réponses et vous avez démontré une progression régulière.");
            else if(k>8) // very good - linear progression
                title34.setText("Excellent - votre meilleur score est de " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        "  bonnes réponses et vous avez démontré une progression régulière.");
            else
                title34.setText("Très bien - vous avez démontré une progression régulière. Vous devez améliorer votre score.");
        else{
            if(i>j && i>k)
                l = i;
            if(j>i && j>k)
                l = j;
            else
                l = k;
            if(l>12)
                title34.setText("Excellent score! il est de " + Integer.toString(k) +
                        " bonnes réponses. Vous devez juste améliorer votre progression.");
            else if (l>8) {
                title34.setText("Très bien - votre meilleur score est de " + Integer.toString(l) +
                        "  bonnes réponses. Vous devez améliorer votre progression.");
            } else
                title34.setText("Essayez encore!");
        }
    }

    back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm following what you're saying, but don't you want an `else` in front of `if (j > i && j > k)`?

Comment: yes. exactly. sorry for the disturbance and many thanks!